# Difference between *(matrix1+i) and *matrix1[i]?

Tags: c

Here's my source code which is self-explanatory, I hope to get some help in here. Everything works fine for **matrix1** but the code in the loop for **matrix2** generates an error. What's the difference between `*(matrix1+i)` and `*matrix1[i]`? I don't see any `=(`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void example(){
int i;
int qty = 5;
char **matrix1 = (char**)malloc(qty*sizeof(char));//matrix example(1)
char **matrix2 = (char**)malloc(qty*sizeof(char));//matrix example(2)
    for(i=0;i<qty;i++){
    //Why the heck may i allocate each vector in this way:
    *(matrix1+i) = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    //...but not in this way(the code below generates an error):
    *matrix2[i] = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));

    //And why the heck may i use strcpy this way:
    strcpy(*(matrix1+i),"some string");
    //...but not in this way(the code below generates an error):
    strcpy(*matrix2[i],"some string");
    }
}

int main(void){
example();
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of `,alloc` & friends in C. Hint: `*matrix1[i]` is the same as `**(matrix1+i)`. Notice the difference?

Comment: `*matrix[i]` is the same as `**(matrix + i)`.

Comment: Yes, i see, now it seems so obvious to me =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*(matrix1+i)` is a pointer to the row with index `i` in the 2dimensional array `char** matrix1` and has type `char*`. But `*matrix2[i]` is the first element of the row with index `i` and has type `char`.

While `*(matrix1+i)` is the same as `matrix1[i]`, is `*matrix2[i]` the same as `**(matrix2+i)`.

Adapt your code like this:

```
char **matrix1 = (char**)malloc(qty*sizeof(char));//matrix example(1)
char **matrix2 = (char**)malloc(qty*sizeof(char));//matrix example(2)
for(i=0;i<qty;i++){

    *(matrix1+i) = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    matrix2[i] = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`*(matrix1+i)` is equivalent to `matrix1[i]` and is of type `char *`, while `*matrix2[i]` is dereferencing the pointer `matrix1[i]` and is of type `char`.

Answer (score 2):

`a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)`.

So the difference between `*(matrix1+i)` and `*matrix1[i]` is the number of `*`s:

- in the former, there's one,
- in the latter, there are two (one of them hidden behind the `[]` syntax).